# Why is the static array member variable showing nothing after calling the instance of the object?

Tags: c++, oop, methods, static, constants

Currently working on Object Oriented Programming in c++ and having problems with an instance showing nothing changed from a method I've created.

The whole code is based off of this object I've created from a header file.

```
#ifndef DEQUE_H_
#define DEQUE_H_


#include <iostream>

const int CAPACITY = 5;
const int DEFAULT = -1;

class Deque
{
public:
    Deque();
    int get_size() const;
    bool is_empty() const;
    bool is_full() const;
    int operator[](int i) const;
    static Deque insert_tail(int);
private:
    int size_;
    static int array_[CAPACITY];
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &, const Deque &);


#endif
```

One of the problems I'm having is the insert_tail method that doesn't show any changes to my static array. 
In the cpp file itself.. these are the function declarations.

#

```
include <iostream>
#include "Deque.h"

Deque::Deque()
    :size_(0)
{

}
int Deque::array_[5] = {};
int Deque::get_size() const
{
    return size_;
}

bool Deque::is_full() const
{
    if (size_ == 5) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

bool Deque::is_empty() const
{
    if (size_!= 5) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int Deque::operator[](int i) const
{

    int something = array_[i];
    return something;
}

Deque Deque::insert_tail(int x)
{
    Deque d;
    d.size_ += 1;
    int size = d.size_;
    d.array_[size - 1] = x;

    return d;
}

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & cout, const Deque & dq)
{
    cout << dq.get_size() << " [ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < dq.get_size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << dq[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "]";

    return cout;
}
```

The operator works just fine. The bools work just fine and the remove_head and remove_tail thing I'll do once I figure out insert tail. Right now, it's not making any chances to the very object I've created inside the main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Deque.h"

void print(const Deque & deque)
{
    static int i = 1;
    std::cout << i << ". " << deque << ", empty: " << deque.is_empty()
            << ", full: " << deque.is_full();
    i++;
}

void test_insert_tail(Deque & deque, int x)
{
    deque.insert_tail(x);
    print(deque); std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Deque deque;
    print(deque);
    std::cout << "\n";
    test_insert_tail(deque, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output should look like this, 
1. 1 [ 2 ], empty: 0, full: 0
but looks like this
1. 0 [], empty: 1, full: 0

What's going on inside my static method for handling all the private attributes that I'm missing on? What did I do wrong exactly?

Comment: The whole *point* of *static* members is that they are *not* associated with an object instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is the misuse of the static word. In fact, static means that is not associated with an instance of the object: this means that the content of the static member (the `array_` variable in this case) is shared between every instance you will create.

That's the same for the `insert_tail` method, that can be used even if you don't create an instance. Now, let's try to understand what you've written in this method:

```
Deque d;
d.size_ += 1;
int size = d.size_;
d.array_[size - 1] = x;
return d;
```

In the first line, you created a new `Deque` object. That's the first mistake, cause you're not modifying the actual `Deque`. Then you add the operations, and in the end, you return the created Deque. However, this object is not saved anywhere, because when you call `deque.insert_tail()` you aren't assigning the returned value anywhere.

Let's try and get this a little bit more concrete.

Since what you're doing is creating a data structure, you won't need any static member. This because everything needs to be saved inside the data structure.

Then, inside the `insert_tail` you'll need to remove the object you created inside. It'll look something like this:

```
size_ += 1;
int size = size_;
array_[size - 1] = x;
```

With those two modifications the code will probably work as expected, however, I suggest you focus on improving the appearance of your code. Using the underscore character at the end of the variable name is a little bit confusing. In C the only scenario you can use it inside the name `int foo_bar` for normal variables, and at the beginning `int _foo` for reserved variables.

Comment: I've kept the insert_tail as static and made the following changes inside. 

Problem is that I can't "access" any changes to size_. It's saying there's an invalid use of static member. What exactly is the deal?

Comment: You don't have to keep `insert_tail` static. In fact, you don't have to use `static` at all in this case.

Comment: See here's the thing. I kept the type of the function as Deque and made it const to access all the private attributes. What's bugging me is that the only real way for me to access the .size_ attribute is making a new instance from that object. Even with all the changes like that, nothing is still showing up. It's really bizarre.

Comment: FIGURED IT OUT!
YES!

Utilize the function as a "pointer" and reference the very object with a *this pointer!

YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Since you figured it out, I think it would be nice if you edited your own post with what you've done to solve this, or if you post another answer with the solution. I'm curious on how you did it!